# Firebase-Dart: Apparent Race Condition When Uploading an Image

Tags: firebase, dart, firebase-storage

using `task.onStateChanged` to detect when the upload is successful. Unfortunately, firebase will not always set state to 'success' when the upload completes. `onStateChanged` will receive a last event where state == 'running' and bytesTransferred == totalBytes. After this event there are no more events that get pushed to `onStateChanged`.

I tried to get around this by exiting in the case where bytesTransferred == totalBytes however, this results in a race condition when I call 
`await task.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();` as it turns out that bytesTransferred == totalBytes yet the `downloadUrl` does not exist yet!

Anyone have a way around this beyond polling to check that the url exists?

Code:

```
 Future<String> uploadImg(File img) async {
    final task = await fb.storage().ref(PATH + img.name).put(img);
    await _monitor(task, IMG_TASK_NAME);
    final uri = await task.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    return uri.toString();
  }

 Future<void> _monitor(fb.UploadTask task, String taskName) {
    final completer =  Completer<bool>();
    task.onStateChanged.listen((fb.UploadTaskSnapshot snapshot) async {
      final state = snapshot.task.jsObject.snapshot.state;

      // fb doesn't always set state == 'success' when done :(
      final isComplete = snapshot.bytesTransferred == snapshot.totalBytes;

      if(state == 'success') {
        completer.complete();
      }
      else if(state == 'error') {
        completer.completeError(taskName);
      }
    });
    return completer.future;
  }
```

Comment: You listen to `onData ` event. Maybe you need listen  to `onDone` event too? As specified in example https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files ` Handle successful uploads on complete
  // For instance, get the download URL: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/...`

Comment: I Have to reopen thi

Comment: Are you using package:firebase with the web or Flutter?

Comment: using w the web